# Dequeue script, but still use wp_localize_script to pass vars

Tags: plugin-development

I need to dequeue some scripts but still have access to the vars passed via their [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) calls. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so, since localize output is tied to script's print event. You will probably have to access that data and output it in some other way.